# Filter with the Time in LINUX

Tags: linux, datetime, awk

I have text file that containing two columns and im trying to write a linux code to filter data. The data has "pass" & "fail" status. I need to Show all "pass" lines , when previous line is "fail" and both lines should be within the 30 second of time. pls help me to do this job. thank you. below shows my text file

```
12/3/2017 13:25:16 AM    fail
12/3/2017 13:25:35 AM    pass
12/3/2017 14:55:11 AM    pass
12/5/2017 23:46:31 AM    pass
12/7/2017 13:15:35 AM    pass
12/7/2017 19:25:51 AM    pass
12/1/2017 15:39:09 AM    fail
12/1/2017 15:39:20 AM    pass
12/9/2017 21:25:45 AM    pass
12/5/2017 16:25:51 AM    pass
```

my required result

```
12/3/2017 13:25:35 AM    pass
12/1/2017 15:39:20 AM    pass
```

Comment: Learn to use [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html). Or code some Python script (or some C program) to do the job. See [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) & perhaps [regex(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html). You *write-my-code* or *do-my-homework* is off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'function get_time(d_str){ 
         split(d_str, d, /[/:[:space:]]/); 
         return mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",d[3],d[1],d[2],d[4],d[5],d[6])) 
     }
     $4=="pass" && status=="fail" && (get_time(prev_date)-get_time($1" "$2))<=30;
     { prev_date=$1" "$2; status=$4 }' file
```

The output:

```
12/3/2017 13:25:35 AM    pass
12/1/2017 15:39:20 AM    pass
```

---

- `function get_time(d_str){ ... }` - returns *timestamp* converted from `d_str`(*datetime* string)