# retrieve data rows in a specific time period in LINUX command

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm developing some LINUX code to filter some data from the cus.txt file. below shows the table in text format

```
12/3/2017  13:25:16  SAM      reject
12/3/2017  13:25:26  NEEL     pass
12/3/2017  13:25:58  SAM      pass
12/3/2017  14:55:11  COOK     pass
12/13/2017 21:25:45  ANDRUE   pass
12/15/2017 23:46:31  FLINTOF  pass
12/19/2017 16:25:51  KEVIN    pass
12/20/2017 13:15:35  JHON     reject
12/20/2017 13:15:25  ADEM     pass
12/20/2017 13:15:51  JHON     pass
12/22/2017 15:39:09  KEVIN    pass
12/25/2017 19:25:28  SIMON    reject
12/25/2017 19:25:31  JHON     pass
12/25/2017 19:25:38  COOK     pass
12/25/2017 19:25:50  SIMON    pass
12/26/2017 22:19:20  SAM      pass
12/27/2017 20:12:55  KEVIN    pass
```

Here i need is,
If you meet every "reject" word in 4th column, it should check name in name column and filter the next "pass" line with the same name within 30 seconds of time period. below shows my linux code.

```
awk 'function get_time(d_str){ split(d_str, d, /[/:[:space:]]/);
return mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",d[3],d[1],d[2],d[4],d[5],d[6])) }$5=="pass" && status=="reject" &&
(get_time(prev_date)-get_time($1" "$2))<=30;{ prev_date=$1" "$2;
status=$5 }' cus.txt
```

With this code i can filter below results. that is not what i need.

[image]

Above is not my required result. Below shows my needed result:

[image]

Comment: you have changed the original code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680769/filter-with-the-time-in-linux/47681444#47681444 where the "status" field is `$4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use `awk` if required, you can also use a simple shell script and `date -d` to compute the difference in time between the last `reject` and next `pass` with the same `name`. Then just test if the difference is less than or equal to `30` seconds and print the line if it is, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

rdate=   ## empty variables to use for reject
rtime=
rname=

while read -r dt tm nm res; do      ## read date time name result
    if [ "$res" = "reject" ]; then  ## if result "reject"
        rdate="$dt"                 ## save date time name
        rtime="$tm"
        rname="$nm"
    ## elif result is pass, if rname set check name = last reject name
    elif [ -n "$rname" ] && [ "$nm" = "$rname" ]; then 
        ## compute time difference between reject and current
        tmdiff=$(( $(date -d "$dt $tm" +%s) - $(date -d "$rdate $rtime" +%s) ))
        ## if less than or equal to 30 output line
        [ "$tmdiff" -le "30" ] && \
            printf "%-9s %s %-7s %s\n" "$dt" "$tm" "$nm" "$res"
    fi
done <cus.txt
```

**Example Output**

```
$ bash cus.sh
12/20/2017 13:15:51 JHON    pass
12/25/2017 19:25:50 SIMON   pass
```

Comment: fantastic coding.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'function get_time(d_str){ 
         split(d_str, d, /[/:[:space:]]/); 
         return mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",d[3],d[1],d[2],d[4],d[5],d[6])) 
     }
     $4=="pass" && $3==name && (get_time($1" "$2)-get_time(prev_date))<=30;
     $4=="reject"{ prev_date=$1" "$2; name=$3 }' file
```

The output:

```
12/20/2017 13:15:51  JHON     pass
12/25/2017 19:25:50  SIMON    pass
```